# JS Doc for functions with default parameters

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, jsdoc

I've created function description using JSDoc `@param` annotation as follows (using Visual Studio "Add jsdoc comments" plugin). But for default parameters of the function doesn't come with its data type. Even if I checked the JSDoc, I didn't find whether this is the correct syntax to describe default parameters.

Therefore, can anyone confirm whether "Add jsdoc comments" plugin does follow the correct syntax on describing functions.

Check `invoiceUpdate` parameter below (here I'm using TypeScript).

```
  /**
   * @param  {string[]} invoiceIds
   * @param  {string} token
   * @param  {} invoiceUpdate=false
   * @returns Promise
   */
  public async calculateInvoices(
    invoiceIds: string[],
    token: string,
    invoiceUpdate = false,
  ): Promise<string> {
      
     /*
        function body
     */

  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to describe optional parameter with default value, according to [the docs](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#optional-parameters-and-default-values) you should use this syntax:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} [somebody=John Doe] - Somebody's name.
 */
```

So, your code, should be like this:

```js
  /**
   * @param  {string[]} invoiceIds
   * @param  {string} token
   * @param  {boolean} [invoiceUpdate=false] invoiceUpdate
   * @returns Promise
   */
const calculateInvoices=(
    invoiceIds,
    token,
    invoiceUpdate = false,
  )=> {
      
     /*
        function body
     */

  }

  calculateInvoices(['sdf'],'sdf')
```

You can find also a lot of information in recently updated [typescript JSDocs page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html)